# How to convert ASP.NET MVC 3 application to make all the Infragistics(Ignite UI) controls work?

Tags: jquery, infragistics

Can someone tell me the step by step procedure that needs to be followed to make all the controls(Infragistics(Ignite UI)) work in an asp.net mvc3 application.
In their website they mention how to use the controls but I didn't find how to convert.
I added a combo box control to my project. I get errors..
Probably some scripts are not being referred. Surprisingly grid works fine but there is an error in combobox.. So I needed to know what all we need to refer.

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly you mean by "convert".. But you can start by giving more info - what method are you using to refer scripts? What error are you getting? Right now all I can advice is checking out the [Getting Started with Combo](http://help.infragistics.com/NetAdvantage/jQuery/2012.2/CLR4.0?page=igCombo_Getting_Started.html) topic (there's a link on top for the general "Working with resources" topic on top, in case it's not a definition problem).

Comment: From the paragraph that was written it sounds as though you have a specific issue with the combo and you should post details on that specific issue if you want help.  You may also want to reach out to Infragistics support.